# Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for

Tags: tensorflow

I tried saving my model out and then tried to restore it, but seems tensorflow is unable to find the location of the matching files :-

Code to save model output :-

```
import tensorflow as tf

save_file = 'model.ckpt'


weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 3]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3]))


saver = tf.train.Saver()


with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver.save(sess, save_file)
```

Code to restore model

```
import tensorflow as tf

save_file = 'model.ckpt'
tf.reset_default_graph()
weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 3]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3]))
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, 'model.ckpt')
```

I am getting below errors :-

W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for model.ckpt

W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for model.ckpt

Comment: Does it work if you pass `'./model.ckpt'` to `saver.restore()`?

Comment: Did work! i guess tensorflow while loading expects to provide the path but while saving will save to current directory.

Comment: Yes… it's quite a strange inconsistency, I'm afraid. [This issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6893) is tracking the problem, but it's still open as of TensorFlow 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

The `saver.restore()` method will fail unless you pass a path—and not just a filename—as the second argument. To work around this problem, you can call `saver.restore(sess, './model.ckpt')` if you are running the script from the directory containing the checkpoint.